# Problem on mounting partitions after create new account

Tags: partitioning, accounts

I created a new account(administrator) and delete the first account .

In this new account , The partitions are access denied . Some error like these are occur : "You are not owner" "You don't have necessary permission to access "Software"."

I updated my ubuntu , two win7 and one winXP , can any one help me to solve it without risk ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

The previous account is probably the owner of the files in the partition. If the partitions are ext (Linux) you only need to go to a terminal and replace the owner of the files (as you deleted the 1st user, you don't need to access the files with it anymore).

```
sudo chown -R new_user_name /the_place_you_mounted_the_partition
```

-R is to apply the command to all subdirectories, you can check `chown` command with `man chown`

After you can check if it worked using `ls -l /the_place_you_mounted_the_partition`

If you have more users to share the partitions, after that you can create a group, assign the group to the files and place the users that need access in the group.

### SWAP:

In `/etc/fstab`:

```
#Entry for swap partition :
UUID=dff20e79-bdef-4615-b582-6790c45d37a1       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

with UUID = swap partition UUID

### NTFS partitions:

in `/etc/fstab`:

```
#Entry for /dev/sda6 (NTFS partition) :
UUID=01F49D053D1E38F0   /mnt/dados      ntfs-3g defaults,suid,dev,exec,locale=pt_BR.utf8        0       0
```

locale= is only if you need special locale config, you can discard it if English.

Comment: swap is used by root I think and you don't need access to it. NTFS should be owned by `root:root` and chmoded to 777 (`drwxrwxrwx`) and you'll have access. Linux permissions do not apply to NTFS partitions. Will update answer on how to mount swap.

Comment: I can't do that . because of this error during save fstab file:"you don't have necessary permissions".

Comment: you need to edit fstab with sudo (`sudo nano /etc/fstab`) to be able to save the changes

Comment: Thank you ,
but now , after boot Ubuntu , a blue screen appears instead Login screen .
I tried very much to fix it , but at last I had to completely delete it and start my project on Win7 .
"The problem doesn't solved". Try to solve it for others .
Thanks again for your attention .

Comment: The original problem, ownership (and mounting) has been solved and I don't think the blue screen came from that because ubuntu was booting after changing ownership of its partition. Maybe for the other partitions you changed something wrong in fstab, used a wrong UUID, mixed the UUID or mounted in bad or inexistent places. Anyways this is the only file changed and you could repair it with a Live CD instead of wiping the partition if this was the problem.